# Oracle Equivalent of SQL Server's Bitwise Operators

Tags: oracle, bitwise-comparison

I am trying to figure out all of the common bit-wise operations in Oracle.

In SQL Server we have some very simple bit-wise operators to use against a bit-wise value:

- `&` - Evaluates if bit exists `select 10 & 2   /* result=2 */`
- `|` - Add Bit (if doesn't exist) `select 10 | 2   /* result=10 */`
- `&~` - Remove Bit (if exists) `select 10 &~ 2  /* result=8 */`
- `^` - Toggle Bit (remove if exists, adds if doesn't) `select 10 ^ 2  /* result = 8 */`

In Oracle, I know we have a built-in `bitand()` function which is more or less equivalent to SQL Server `&`, and I have built an Oracle bit-wise `OR` function to mimic SQL server's bit-wise `OR` operation (`|`) as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION BITOR (x IN NUMBER, y IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER AS
    BEGIN
       RETURN x + y - BITAND(x,y);
    END;
```

**My question is**: how can I achieve the SQL Server `&~` and the `^` operations in Oracle?

Comment: `BITXOR(x,y) = BITOR(x,y) - BITAND(x,y) = x + y - 2*BITAND(x,y)`

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked [the manual?](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_raw.htm#ARPLS71353), it should help with your question to a large extent.